# python pickle load object AttributeError because of __attrs__

Tags: python, serialization, pickle

I am using pickle dump my class to a file as follow, but I got `AttributeError` when print loaded object's attribute.

```
import cPickle as pickle
from requests.sessions import Session

class B(Session):
    def __init__(self, b):
        super(B, self).__init__()
        self.b = b

if __name__ == '__main__':
    b = B(2,)

    with open('/tmp/b.pl', 'wb') as f:
        pickle.dump(b, f)

    with open('/tmp/b.pl', 'rb') as f:
        t = pickle.load(f)
        print t.headers
        print t.b # AttributeError
```

anyway, I find how to solve this problem, just define `B` like as follow:

```
class B(Session):
    __attrs__ = [
        'headers', 'cookies', 'auth', 'proxies', 'hooks', 'params', 'verify',
        'cert', 'prefetch', 'adapters', 'stream', 'trust_env',
        'max_redirects', 'b'
    ]
    def __init__(self, b):
        super(B, self).__init__()
        self.b = b
```

then that is ok. It seems that the reason is `__attrs__`, then I tried to test this:

```
class A(object):
    __attrs__ = []
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a
class C(A):
    def __init__(self, a, c):
        super(C, self).__init__(a)
        self.c = c

if __name__ == '__main__':
    b = B(2,)
    c = C(1, 2)
    with open('/tmp/c.pl', 'wb') as f:
        pickle.dump(c, f)

    with open('/tmp/c.pl', 'rb') as f:
        t = pickle.load(f)
        print t.a
        print t.c
```

But, I got no Error, why is this?

Comment: I don't have `requests.sessions` module installed (python 2.7 or 3.4), but one cause that I could think of is that `Session` defines one of  `__getinitargs__` or `__getstate__` (which you would have to override). Check [pickle protocol](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#pickle-protocol).

Comment: @CristiFati you are right. I got `state = dict((attr, getattr(self, attr, None)) for attr in self.__attrs__)` in `__getstate__ `